# Which separation axiom?

Tags: general-topology, terminology

Let $X$ be a topological space. Assume that for all $x_1,x_2 \in X$ there exist open neighbourhoods $U_i$ of $x_i$ such that $U_1 \cap U_2 = \emptyset$. Such a space, as we all know, is called [Hausdorff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hausdorff_space). What would we call a space, and which separation axioms would the space satisfy, if $\overline{U_1} \cap \overline{U_2} = \emptyset$ for all $x_i \in X$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Such a space is known as $T_{2\frac{1}{2}}$ or Urysohn according to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_axiom).

Comment: Seriously? **5** seconds apart? :-)

Comment: @Asaf You just have to rub it in my face... ;-)

Comment: I'll let you have this one...